# Listed items positioning issue in ExpressionEngine

Tags: templates, tags

I have a positioning issue with my in ExpressionEngine. On the following link scroll down to the roster section:  [click here](http://thecharlesnyc.com/dev/dgi/ExpressionEngine/index.php)

I am looping the `li` tags for `<ul class="roster-grid">` I have noticed it loops fine on the few row however begins to misalign on the third row onwards. Does any one know what is causing this problem?

```
<ul class="roster-grid">
{exp:channel:entries channel="roster" dynamic="no" orderby="date" sort="asc"}
                {roster_music limit="1"}
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="{music_thumb}" alt="music" alt="grid-img"></a>
                </li>
                {/roster_music}
{/exp:channel:entries}
            </ul>
```

Comment: this is CSS. If you change the width on the LI containing DJ ruckus to 177px everything lines up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did noticed that there are a mixture of image sizes in the grid. Some are `178x182`, `178x183` & `177x183`. This might be causing break in the grid. Try setting a consistant width & height on the images.

Also looks like the `.roster-grid` isn't quite wide enough. I increased the width by one pixel to `534px` and the image jump back. But, this could be do to the inconsistant image dimensions.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks, sorry it's been a long day, my brain is abit scrabbled